# Random Sparse Matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix, graph, pytorch

I want to create a random sparse matrix in python, where the non - zero elements are between 1 and 7 and the diagonal elements are zero. Also no row or column should have all elements zero. The % of zero elements also would be chosen randomly. Also, if i,j is non-zero, then j,i should be 0.

I have the following so far, I have not been able to figure out how to ensure that rows and columns are not always all 0 and how to make sure that if i,j is non-zero then j,i should be zero.

```
Lij = np.random.randint(1,10,size=n * n) Lij =
Lij.reshape(nbanks,nbanks) np.fill_diagonal(Lij, 0)
num_replaced = np.round(0.7 * Lij.shape[0]*Lij.shape[1])
indices_x = np.random.randint(0, Lij.shape[0], int(num_replaced)) 
indices_y = np.random.randint(0, Lij.shape[1], int(num_replaced)) 
Lij[indices_x, indices_y] = 0
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "The % of zero elements also would be chosen randomly"  - what distribution ?

Comment: It should be uniform (0,1)

Comment: between 0 and 1% percent or between 0 and 100% ?   both interpretations are unworkable,  frequently picking too few or too many filled cells.

Comment: @Jasen 0 to 100% ideally. But what range would be workable?

Comment: you can't hase 50% or more full be cause the x,y swap of each full cell needs to be empty, also the diagonal,   you can't have less than 1/n because there needs to be one full on each line.

Comment: @Jasen Got it. So if I truncate it to say 25-50%, how do I need to modify my code?

Answer (score 0):

a possible algorithm would be to pick coordinates from a list at ramdom and if the xy and yx are both available and x != y then set a value in that coordinate. continue until you have enough percentage fill.

afterwards check that all rows have at-least one non-zero.